# Can we write extensions for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can we write extensions for Visual Studio Code?

[Atom supports custom packages](https://atom.io/docs/v0.194.0/hacking-atom-tools-of-the-trade)

Can we build an extension?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of 18/11/2015 it is indeed possible to create extensions for Visual Studio Code.

There are many extensions already available on the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/#VSCode)

You can read more about it in: [Extending Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview)

Comment: node js modules are not published when extension is published like mode FS module , open module. How to tackle that?

Comment: @ShanKhan no idea. You should probably post a question.

Comment: its working fine in my computer but when downloaded doesnt work. Posted question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create a specific language support by create a new directory under **C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.1.0\resources\app\plugins**, the format doesn't seem that difficult to understand.